# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if' SQL Command

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-express

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I get the error : Incorrect syntax near the key word 'if'. This is the code that is giving me issues. I want to create a database and if it doesn't exists. What am I doing wrong?

````
   connection.Open();
   var dbCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
   dbCommand.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE if not exists StockNotesDB;";
   dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();```
````

Comment: Not really. I would to keep it in one line if possible to make it simple?

Comment: I guess if not exists causes issues but I don't know why.

Comment: It causes issues because it is incorrect syntax, as the error says. You can't do this in one statement.

Comment: But its possible with Create Table If Not Exists? I've seen this work.

Comment: What database are you using (MySql, Oracle, MSSQL)? I'm not aware of `create table if not exists` syntax for MSSQL which is what I assumed, but maybe I assumed wrong.

Comment: I'm using SQL Express. Sorry I am new to SQL so I'm learning.

Comment: Different Database systems have different features. You can't use that syntax with MSSQL/SQLExpress/LocalDB

Comment: You could just  run CREATE DATABASE. If it exists it'll fail; ignore the exception and you're  in the same place as you were with your IF